# Fedora 19 - Not able to establish Wi-Fi connection

Tags: connection, wifi, installation, fedora

currently I am using Fedora 19 (since a few days) but the setup of Wi-Fi let me going crazy. I'm using the Realtek RTL 8192CU Wi-Fi-adapter usb-dongle. Fedora recognizes my network, I enter the **right** password and using the correct encryption option, but the system still asking for the password.

Does anyone has a solution for my problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

- Run `yum update` to make sure your system is up to date. Run `yum install @'Developer Tools' if you have not previously installed the GNU build tools.`
- Download the latest drivers from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) (Version 3.4.4_4749)
- Download this [patch](http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/80801107/file.html).

Extract the driver. In the directory "driver," there is another zip, extract that as well. Finally put the patch in that folder.

CD into the zip you extracted from the command line and type:
`patch -p1 < use_kthread_run.patch`

Type make, followed by make install. Finally you need to run `modprobe 8192cu`. You may also want to blacklist the previous driver.

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/messages for NetworkManager messages.  You should see what is failing there.